# frictionless sharing using facebook open graph fails intermittently - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I perform the action I want to show on facebook activities I sometimes get this error code (especially with an object that I haven't previously or recently interacted with):

> open graph log: error: domain = com.facebook.sdk, code = 5

upon repeating the action it just eventually works, shows the activity properly on facebook and returns a message that looks like this:

> open graph log: Posted Open Graph action, id: 10151538299634942

The open graph information is embedded in pages on our web server and self.recipe.URLatThisApp is the URL for the object. I've been trying to debug this and I'm not sure where the error lies. Would appreciate any pointers.

Note: We just tested this on our website, and the open graph frictionless sharing on the website behaves the same way. So we don't believe that the issue is iOS specific or we are making the same mistake in both our iOS and web implementations.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:self.recipe.URLatThisApp forKey:@"recipe"];
    NSLog(@"OPEN GRAPH SAVE");
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/ThisAppns:save" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSString *alertText;
        if (!error) {
            alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"Posted Open Graph action, id: %@",
                         [result objectForKey:@"id"]];
        } else {
            alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                         error.domain, error.code];
        }
        /*
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                    message:alertText
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks!"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil]
         show];
         */
        NSLog(@"open graph log: %@", alertText);
    }

     ];


}
```